# After disabling WPML multi currency, the currency is still handled by the WPML

Tags: php, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-wpml

I have used WPML multi currency for a while, but recently I turned it off and use the other currency plugin.

Most of the amount have converted correctly,  but for some amount still remain at the default currency even after I changed to another one:

1) Booking cost from Woocommerce Booking plugin

2) Extra option cost and total cost from Extra options plugin

The amount is obtain using AJAX , from the actions:

1) wc_bookings_calculate_costs

2) tc_epo_bookings_calculate_costs

After some studies , I found the amount is calculate at :

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/compatibility/class-wcml-bookings.php

The code : https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-multilingual/blob/master/compatibility/class-wcml-bookings.php 
(the wc_bookings_calculate_costs is refered at line 163, and it goes to the  function filter_wc_booking_cost at line 731)

So, it is quite strange as I already disabled the multi currency in WPML settings.

I suspect at some where the code still goes to the WPML currency, how to fix that?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

First at all, I just use WPML one time and I really don't liked it.

It comes to me, that you maybe leave some po/mo files in the `wp-content/languages/woocommerce-multilingual/` or wpml one.
I found on a [thread](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-get-wpml-to-use-mo-files/) saying

> 1. Visit WPML > Theme and plugin localization > select 'Translate using .mo files' > select Automatically load the theme's .mo file
>      using 'load_theme_textdomain'. > Enter textdomain > Save
> 2. The translations for wordpress and the admin screen are those to be placed in wp-content/languages - Download these files here:
>      http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/
> 3. Your theme's language should be put in a themes/awr-theme/languages/ directory
> 4. Finally the naming of this file must match the language options set on your site. If your using Spanish in it's without changing the
>      locale setting, WPML is associating es_ES.mo. You can review those
>      options if you visit WPML > Languages > Site Languages > Edit
>      Languages.

Why not, this will explain this ghost plugin behaviour !? As woocommerce-multiligual compatibility check for other plugin option... Add with some custom template files, translation string, that can be understood.

Depending on how you deactivate (and delete ?) the plugin, is it possible that some options settings of multi-currency plugins remains in your install ?

Are you sure that any code (yours or another plugin or theme) is not calling `class-wcml-bookings.php` directly (without is_plugin_active() ), and by this way reactivate some actions and filter ? But I really doubt about this fact, as the class is not initiate, all filter reference will br broken.

In case I'm wrong, about the filter you are talking about line 163

```
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', array( $this, 'filter_wc_booking_cost' ), 10, 4 );
```

Did you try to remove it with `remove_filter()` ?

```
remove_filter('get_post_metadata', 10, 4);
```

Writing this I lean more on mo/po way than filter.

Hope it helps!

Comment: the pluguin is activated though, because I need the language translation, but I have disabled the multi currency in WPML setting page

Answer (score 0):

Before you wreck your self check your WC settings -> tools page and first try to clear all trancients and do recount of terms. WC uses trancients and these need to be cleared some times.